# .Net MVC pagination library

Tags: web-development, .net, mvc

I am working on my first .Net MVC project, and I need paging support on several pages.

What library do you recommend for this?

Comment: No comment by the downvoter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/)

Its used in the [paging section of the getting started tutorial on asp.net itself](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a decent [pager](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-pager) and [pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) tool, as well as other useful tools.

Another option would be using [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).

I've also rolled my own pager from time to time.

It's really dependent on how you intend to use it. If you're basically making a really big table and all the information is the same, I'd recommend the datatables because it easily implements sorting, searching AND paging.
However, if you're bringing different types of data across, you might find something like jQuery's [tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) more useful.